# Xcode Error: "The app ID cannot be registered to your development team."

Tags: ios, xcode

We are porting an Android app to iOS for a client. They have added our account to their iTunes Connect account and created an app entry. We developed the app using the bundle ID they specified.

But now, when the app is ready for testing, we can't create a provisioning profile in Xcode. It is set to Automatic signing and this error is shown:

> Failed to create provisioning profile.
>
> The app ID "<bundle-id>" cannot be registered to your development team. Change your bundle identifier to a unique string to try again.

Our account is added as an App Manager in their iTunes Connect account, but still we can't take output with this ID. This error is not shown if we change the bundle ID in Xcode.

Comment: make sure your app bundle identifier in app settings/plist & in Provisioning profiles match. Also downloaded all the profiles from xcode->preference-> account. Also cross verify your keys .. Try to uncheck the automatic then check the error , & select your team profile correctly while building.

Comment: Actually we are on the step of generating provisioning profile. Tried unchecking the Automatic signing and then cleaned project. Again checked the automatic signing, selected the correct team. But the same error is shown.

Comment: Did you ever find the solution?

Comment: No. The client generated the profiles and certificates and gave it to us.

Comment: Like the error has explained itself, the id string may have been registered by another team.

Answer (score 104):

Meet same Issue on one mac, but ok on another mac.
I'm sure bundle ID is fine and unique.

I know it is provisioning profile issue, so
Try refreshing the provisioning profile on your Local computer.
Then It Works!

1. `cd ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning\ Profiles`
2. `rm *`
3. Xcode > Preferences... > Accounts > click your Account and Team name > click `Download Manual Profiles`
4. Run app again

Comment: Doesn't work with latest xcode version. cd: no such file or directory: ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning\ Profiles/

Comment: @JanMoritz Try `cd '~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/'` (without a backslash before the space between "Provisioning" and "Profiles". I edited the post, so hopefully the correction will show up after peer review.

Comment: This did not work for me, even after a `Clean Build Folder`.

Comment: `cd ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning\ Profiles`

Comment: Thanks, Worked great!

Answer (score 48):

Go to Build Settings tab, and then change the Product Bundle Identifier to another name. It works in mine.

Comment: This will not work for me as the bundle ID should stay the same.

Comment: This problem may occur if the project was signed with a different developer while it was being created. The problem is solved when you change the bundle id as @firda-rinoa-sahidi said.

Comment: Thanks its works but is not a solution, I don't have a developer account(pay), only a personal team account(free), for that reason I'm not see the Certificates panel in Apple Developers Console, then I can not delete that bundle identifier, I think its a bug of xcode/apple developers

Comment: For me the project wouldn't build on a new machine different than the one where I had created the code. Changing the bundle identifier worked (I was able to build and run) and then even with changing it back to the original identifier it still works

Answer (score 35):

You have to rename **Organization Identifier on Bundle Identifier** on settings tab.

[image]

Only by renaming the **Organization Identifier** error will remove.

Comment: We had to use the same identifier as the app will be published in our client's account in the store.

Comment: try to change then REchange the Bundle Identifier into the original one. That did the trick for me.

Comment: So, that is change, (then what here?), then change back

Answer (score 11):

I had this same issue as OP and the problem was that I was invited only on appstoreconnect and not on developer.apple.com. After being invited as a member on developer.apple.com and going into the preferences in XCode, I got a new option to sign as a member of the organization. Setting signing team as member of organization in project settings fixed the issue. After that creating the provisioning profile was successful using automatic signage management.

Comment: I wish I knew this before. Unfortunately, I don't have the tools anymore to check whether this works or not. So, I guess this question will remain as unanswered.

Comment: Yep this worked for me. External company had only invited me to App Store Connect and not Apple Developer.

Answer (score 8):

This happened to me, even though I had already registered the Bundle Id with my account. It turns out that the capitalisation differed, so I had to change the bundle id in Xcode to lowercase, and it all worked. Hope that helps someone else :)

Comment: This is exactly my issue too. I've emailed them to remove the previously registered bundle id from my account, let's see.

Comment: Accidentally I found one deleted character in the bundle id, now fixed it and problem is solved.

Answer (score 6):

Changing Bundle Identifier worked for me.

1. Go to **Signing & Capabilities** tab
2. Change my Bundle Identifier. "MyApp" > "MyCompanyName.MyApp"
3. Enter and wait a seconds for generating Signing Certificate

If it still doesn't work, try again with these steps before:

1. Remove your Provisioning Profiles: `cd /Users/my_username/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles && rm *` (in my case)
2. Clearn your project
3. ...

Comment: This worked for me Xcode 12 Release. None of the other comments had worked for me. Using App Groups for a Widget.

Comment: I change my bundle to my account name it's work for me

Answer (score 3):

If this persists even after clearing provisioning profile and re-downloading them, then it might be due to the bundle ID already registered in Apple's MDM push certificate.

Answer (score 3):

None of the above answers worked for me, and as said in the original question I had also to keep the same bundle identifier since the app was already published in the store by the client.

The solution for me was to ask the client **to change my access from App Manager to Admin,** so that I had "Access to Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles.", you can check if it is the case in the **App Store Connect => Users and Access => and then click on your profile (be sure to choose the right team if you belong to multiple).**

Once you are admin go back to Xcode and in the signing tab **select 'Automatically manage signing', then in Team dropdown you should be able to select the right team  and the signature will work.**

Answer (score 2):

My problem was I was modifying the settings for the wrong version of my app.

[image]

I had "Debug" selected instead of "Release", so my bundle identifier was not accurate when it came time to Archive.

Answer (score 2):

### error message

> The app identifier "my.bundle.id" cannot be registered to your development team because it is not available. Change your bundle identifier to a unique string to try again.

try this

[Apple developer](https://developer.apple.com/) > Account > Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles > Identifiers

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem when I was trying to compile a sample project provided by Apple. In the end I figured out that apparently they pre-compiled the sample code before shipping them to developers, so the binary had their signature.

The way to solve it is simple, just delete all the built binaries and re-compile using your own bundle identifier and you should be fine.

Just go to the menu bar, click on **[Product] -> [Clean Build Folder]** to delete all compiled binaries

[Clean Build Folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L7ows.png)

Answer (score 1):

I had the issue with different development teams. I just checked the schema signings and picked the correct development team for the schemas that I needed:

[image: Ss from Xcode]

Answer (score 1):

I delete the Bundle identifier in the https://developer.apple.com/account/resources/identifiers/list, then it works.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 1):

IF you are working with different build configs then check in Signing & Capabilities Tab are you using Correct Bundle Identifier.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For Xcode v12 and above

- Open the `.xcworkspace` file using Xcode
- Then go directly to the `General` section, you'll see `Bundler Identifier`
- Then change the name in the bundler identifier

for example `com.myapp-dev.app` should be changed to `com.myapp.app`.

This worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had been dealing with this issue since last night. I tried many things written here, and finally, I found my own solution. I'm sharing the solution below to help those who are experiencing the same issue.

> Solution: Open your app in Xcode, then I updated the step that was in the format com.*account*.app_name to com.*account*.app_name-ios, and the problem was resolved.

I hope I have been able to help.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the original bundle identifier to work on my paid team membership account (after having it assigned to my personal team) by revoking the personal team signing certificate that was assigned to the same account id.

1. On the Apple Developer website sign in with the paid account it, go to Certificates, IDs & Profiles.
2. Click the personal team certificate.
3. Click the Revoke button.
4. Go back to XCode and try signing again. A new certificate will be generated that should work with the bundle id.

This won't work if you still need the certificate for other apps.

Answer (score 0):

If none of the above solutions work, you may want to check your folder names. I had another folder, within a separate parent folder but sharing an ancestor directory, with the same name as my project folder.  Renaming the other folder to something else resolved the issue.  If I had to guess, Xcode was looking for the project in the parent directory, found the alternate folder with the same name and got confused...

Answer (score 0):

1. Due to Security issue my client do not want to share the personal credentials. He just add my apple id in developer.apple.com
2. After that I create the certificate from key chain and add it into apple developer Account.
3. My client also add the bundle identifier and send it to me the latest certificate
4. Now you need to add Team account
   Note: You must add team account not your apple id account
   In my case i got 2 ids one of mine muhammadusman17....@gmail.com and the other one is "CHT Team" i just select the CHT Team then its working perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Remove your account from xcode and sign in again:

1. Xcode -> Preferences -> 'Acount' Tab
2. Choose your account and tap '-' in the bottom left corner
3. Tap '+' and sign in to your account again
4. Archive

Answer (score 0):

[image]

As per shown in the picture go to runner and then click on release set your team correctly it will solve your issue thanks

Answer (score 0):

I know it sounds incredible stupid and unbelievable, but what I did to fix it - after 2 hours, was changing my bundle identifier to ***all lowercase*** and ***appending "123" at the end***.

This really solved the issue. I don't know why, as I am not a xcode developer.
The only thing that mattered was getting it running on a physical device.

Comment: Solved by Just --> bundle identifier to all lowercase

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was to simply just delete the identifier from the previous developement team on the page Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles.  [image]

Answer (score 0):

Solved by Just --> bundle identifier to all lowercase

check in apple Developer & same use in Xcode project

Issue will be solved 100%

Answer (score 0):

If you're using flutter, open your app in `xcode`, open your `Runner`, in your runner go to `Build Settings` inside of your build settings, check and make sure that all of your `Development Team` is the same.

Answer (score -1):

At the center top of your XCODE screen, change your device.

For example: Apple Pie>iPad Pro (12.9-inch)(5th generation)

```
----------------------(^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^)
                          ^change this to your device ^
```

Answer (score -1):

Changing the bundle identifier to all lowercase fixed the problem for me

Comment: That does not make any news. Nothing happened. Still error.