# Xcode 11 Archiving to Generic iOS Device errors relating to registering bundle identifier and iOS App Dev provisional profiles matching my app id

Tags: ios, xcode, archive, testflight

As the title says, I'm on Xcode 11 and trying to archive to a generic iOS device to add a new version of the app to TestFlight. It builds fine on all simulators. I don't believe I can change the bundle identifier as I'm adding an update to an app that's already on TestFlight. See below for archive errors.

Errors:

1. "Failed to register bundle identifier. The app identifier "com.'myappnameishere'" cannot be registered to your development team because it is not available. Change your bundle identifier to a unique string and try again."
2. No profiles for 'com.myappnameishere' were found: Xcode couldn't find any iOS App Development provisioning profiles matching 'com.myappnameishere'

What I've done:

- A. Gotten an Apple Developer Account and registered my devices
- B. Cleared the local Provisional Profiles using this method: 
  [Xcode Error: "The app ID cannot be registered to your development team."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44160993/xcode-error-the-app-id-cannot-be-registered-to-your-development-team)

Apologies if this has already been posted but I couldn't find anything. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

1. If the app is already on TestFlight, you cannot just use any apple developer id, you need to be logged in with the same apple dev account which was used to upload the app to TestFlight before
2. To archive, and upload an update to the app, you will also need the following installed in your machine

   - **app store provisioning profile** for the bundle id
   - **certificate** assigned to the app store profile
   - **private key** for the certificate's
     (or you need to create these artefacts, and install / download them on your machine)

It is not clear if you already meet these criteria.

EDIT: answers to questions in your comment -

1. You may also face issues running the app on the device if you do not have developer profile for the bundle id, but with free provisioning / wildcard profile, you can circumvent this, and not need access to the specific dev account.
2. You can create and export archive (generate ipa file) ready for testflight using those artefacts, but to upload the ipa to testflight [using any method](https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/devb1c185036), you will need credentials for the specific dev account. Alternatively, you can generate the ipa and share it with someone who has access and can upload the ipa.

Comment: So, just to clarify, 1. the apple developer id is tied to a specific developer account, and this ONLY matters when you are uploading to TestFlight. (Or could it also throw a build error?) 2. It's possible to gain the app store provisioning profile for the bundle id, certificate, private key for the certificate WITHOUT the same apple developer id and thereby archive a new TestFlight update w/o said app dev id. Thanks again.

Comment: @GarrettPost I had answered your question in the comment ere in comments, but them to and edit in the main answer, as it might be useful for someone else who reads the answer. Please check the *EDIT* section above.