# React Native XCode: Should I have to create a new bundle identifier?

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, react-native-ios

My collaborator chose the bundle identifier `com.company.app`, and when I forked the repo and tried to build the project in XCode, it said `The app ID cannot be registered to your development team because it is not available`. I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44160993/xcode-error-the-app-id-cannot-be-registered-to-your-development-team) that the only solution that worked for me was to manually change the name of the bundle identifier in XCode. This doesn't seem like it should be the right solution. Shouldn't my collaborator and I be able to use the same bundle identifier?

Comment: Your collaborator needs to add you to their Apple development team

Comment: I am on their Apple developer team

Comment: Then make sure that is the team you have selected in your project in Xcode