Failed Registering Bundle Identifier Xcode

The app identifier "com.package.name" cannot be registered to your development team because it is not available.
Change your bundle identifier to a unique string to try again.
No profiles for 'com.package.name' were found
Xcode couldn't find any iOS App Development provisioning profiles matching 'com.pacakge.name'.
How to fix this problem

seems like this bundler registered already or your team has  already registered then you have load profiles first for this. Please refer this  question : https://stackoverflow.com/q/44160993/4373661

is there any reason you didn't just take a normal screenshot on the Mac?


Check if the bundle identifier is already registered under your Apple Developer account in Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles:

Visit: https://developer.apple.com/account/resources


If you are unsure how to set up Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles, refer to this guide:

https://medium.com/@CadenBurleson/how-to-setup-certificates-identifiers-profiles-to-put-your-iphone-game-onto-your-phone-for-fe59f42a9ffb


Ensure you have the correct provisioning profile and re-download it in Xcode:

Step 1: Go to Xcode -> Settings -> Accounts -> Select your account and download the profiles manually.
Step 2: In Xcode, open your project -> Go to Signing & Capabilities -> Disable Automatically manage signing and then re-enable it. This should refresh and fix any profile issues.




Thank you for your detailed and helpful response regarding the setup of Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles. Your guidance, including the steps to verify the bundle identifier and manage provisioning profiles in Xcode, was incredibly valuable.
Following your instructions, I was able to resolve the issue successfully. I appreciate the time and effort you took to provide such a clear and actionable solution.
Thanks once again for your support!
